# How can I get those two processes (programs) talk to each other directly using pipes?

Tags: python, pipe, stdout, stdin, stdio

Program A, is a c program that endlessly, receives input in stdin, process it and output it to stdout.

I want to write program B (in python) so it will reads A's output, and feed it back with whatever is needed. 
Note there must be only one instance of each of those programs, so given b1 and b2 which are instances of b instead of:

```
$ b1 | a | b2
```

I need to have

```
$ b1 | a | b1
```

The following is the diagram of the final desired result:

[image]

Comment: What's the stop condition? As you've defined, unless your programs write to disk or output to `stderr`, they'll continue to loop infinitely until a sentinel like `EOF` or `SIGINT` is given.

Comment: @MrGomez, no worry about that. quit can be passed via stdin. besides, they are meant to run endlessly ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) class to create a subprocess for program A.  For example:

```
import subprocess
import sys

# Create subprocess with pipes for stdin and stdout
progA = subprocess.Popen("a", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Reassign the pipes to our stdin and stdout
sys.stdin = progA.stdout
sys.stdout = progA.stdin
```

Now the two processes can communicate back and forth with each other via the pipes.  It might also be a good idea to save the original `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` into other variables so that if you ever decide to terminate the subprocess, you can restore stdin and stdout to their original states (e.g. the terminal).

Comment: I'd skip the assignments sys.std*, just use the progA.stdout and ProgA.stdin objects directly. That way you don't lose standard output.

Comment: that re-assign is the part I missed. many thanks! (have to wait now 8 minutes to be able to mark your answer as accepted answer)

Comment: @Winston Ewert: I agree, that's probably the better option, but since OP took the time to make such a nice diagram, he probably has a good reason for wanting to reassign stdin and stdout.

Answer (score 1):

For those who come here by Google: there is actually a very good way using named pipes:

first create 2 names pipes:

```
mkfifo pipe1
mkfifo pipe2
```

then run this:

```
echo -n x | cat - pipe1 > pipe2 & cat <pipe2 > pipe1
```

this will cause the cat commands to copy the letter x all the time to each other. So now you can feel free to use your own programs instead of cat, to process the input and output. This is not limited to python. You can also connect a java program with a c++ program.

For example if your programs are called A.py and B.py the initial command would be:

```
echo -n x | ./A.py - pipe1 > pipe2 & ./B.py <pipe2 > pipe1
```